# Exporting a PowerPoint slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've got a macro in a PowerPoint file that is to export the first slide to a TIF image. It was working before but now has started to give an error. The following is the line of code I use to export the image and it is the line that gives me the error.

```
Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Export "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\picture.TIF", "TIF"
```

The error that I get is:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> Slide (unknown member) : Failed.

I've tried searching on Google and can't figure this one out. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The specified graphics format must have an export filter registered in the Windows registry. You can specify either the registered extension or the registered filter name. Is TIF a registered format on your system? What happens if you try to use a format like JPG? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.export

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides

Comment: why dont you just export the slide normally?

Answer (score 0):

The command itself is correct, the user has in the meantime sent testfiles. I suspect a general permission problem in writing files which can be checked with this:

```
Sub CreateFile()
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim InfoText As String
Dim iCnt As Integer
Dim sFileName As String
iCnt = FreeFile
For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
InfoText = InfoText & "Slide " & oSld.SlideIndex & " Shape " & oShp.Name & vbCrLf & "------------" & vbCrLf
Next ' oShp
Next ' oSld
sFileName = "D:\InfoTestFile.txt"
Open sFileName For Output As iCnt
Print #iCnt, InfoText
Close iCnt
Call Shell("NOTEPAD.EXE " & sFileName, vbNormalFocus)
MsgBox "If this works I have no idea anymore hahaha", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried to export to hard disk but that didn't make a difference. I'm using this on Windows 10 and PowerPoint 2016. It's really strange as it was working before. This was developed as part of a rudimentary drawing application were we use my powerpoint template to create a simple drawing then run a macro to export it to a tif file.

Exporting the entire presentation works though. i.e. Application.ActivePresenetation.Export. That is my current work around. For some reason it doesn't like it when I try to export an individual slide.

Comment: Did you try my barebone code?
--> Because: Is that the only line in your code or is there more context (which could lead to the error) which we don't see?
Can you try it on a different computer? 
Did you try it with a new empty ppt (in case your file is somehow corrupted)

Again - it works perfect for me - so the error must be in your file or your computer

Comment: I tried the barebones code in a brand new file and got someone else to test it on another pc too and both get errors. I have however set up a work around by exporting all slides and copying the one i need.

Comment: Since I tried this code also on two pcs and it works perfectly I am really curious about the weird error you get (even on another computer). Could you send me the barebone file for checking?

Comment: What's the best way to send you the file? Does stackoverflow have private messaging?

Comment: Just use a cloud folder - like OneDrive, GoogleDrive or whatever and post the link. Like here where you can find your barebone test: https://1drv.ms/p/s!AkGlxzeLVEwsmPx3OZEq-Ye2GMJ0Tg?e=X6fOT6

Comment: I've downloaded your test file and I get the same error. It must the version of PowerPoint that my company has.
Here's my test file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwtqmGnnzaS8zVDT5oSLzUpyvwhfmrtn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, apparently @wozza this must be on your system which I suspected. This link for yours unfortunately does not allow me to download your file - it just opens it in Google ;-) please make a zip file first and make sure I have the rights for download. See you

Comment: Try this one
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uqx7szACS8nMtTptzwTo42uAmIq4WI-U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @wozza I sent code in the edited answer above -- check if that works because I suspect a permission problem on the target computer.

Comment: It works. i have no idea too. I gave up and used a work around. We have all sorts of permissions stuff put in place by our IT so I wouldn't be surprised if it was a permissions issue. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Wow -- that's amazing - you used D: both times? Than it is really puzzling. Glad to hear you found a workaround..

Comment: Yes, D: both times. Very strange indeed. i guess this will be one of life's unsolved mysteries...

Comment: Than it can't be a permission problem. Well, I did my best ...